# KendoMobile dataSource didn't initialize properly

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource, kendo-mobile

I'm currently developping a little KendoMobile WebApp.
My problem is quite simple :
Anytime I try to initialize a dataSource by setting an Array as its data option, the dataSource remains empty.

Here is my array (screen from safari dev console) :

```
console.log("fournisseursArray -> ");
console.log(fournisseursArray);
```

[image: fournisseursArray]

Now this is the structure of my objects :

[image]

In my opinion both seems correct in fact : when I use the objects from the array, it shows me what I want so I guess it works fine.

But if it was that simple, I wouldn't have to be here, so...

This is how I declare my dataSource :

```
dataSourceMap = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: fournisseursArray
});
```

Finally this is what I get when I put a log on my dataSource :

```
console.log(dataSourceMap);
```

[image]

If someone knows what is the problem, I'll thanks him greatly to share his knowledge with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kendo UI data source will remain empty unless you call the `read` or `fetch` methods. In short call fetch or read before accessing the data.

Comment: It was so simple that I didn't even think about that... Thank you !